# tracking memory allocation in Clojure

Tags: memory, clojure, heap-memory

In my program all the state is held in a giant map in an atom, which is updated by a load of pure functions in each iteration. I have determined that the heap size is increasing, how do I find the code that's responsible ? I tried VisualVM, but it gives generic information and I can't find which part of my state is growing and which function is causing it to grow.

Comment: Do you actually get an `OutOfMemoryError`? It might be nothing to do with your code since it could be that you are seeing the effect of the JVM taking up spare memory to minimise the number of GCs.....

Comment: Agreed with above comment. This is normal, unless you are observing that gc events are *not* causing the used heap to decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look for common gotchas like forgetting to use with-open, hanging onto the head of a sequence, etc.
2. Isolate smaller segments of your code and see if you still see the same kinds of memory growth using JVisualVM. If knocking out or mocking some piece makes no difference then put it back, and if it makes a difference then you can focus on that and figure out what is going on.

I don't know of any silver bullet tool or technique, it's just a process of divide and conquer, and thinking about what you are doing in your code.

Comment: thanks. I haven't had an OutOfMemoryError since I changed several uses of (take... to (vec (take...

Comment: - but have to say, VisualVM doesn't pinpoint *where* in your code your're doing it wrong, only *what* you may be doing wrong